# cherrypy URL issue

Tags: url, cherrypy

i have a URL in cherrypy similar to stackoverflow
like:

```
http://sample.com/post/12345/hello-world
```

but i want to make the following URL works too in cherrypy:

```
http://sample.com/post/12345/hello-world?from=something&else=123
```

and it should be corrected to:

```
http://sample.com/post/12345/hello-world
```

how can i do that?

i am using popargs and _cp_dispatch with no success. any suggestion would be appreciated.

thanks

**EDIT**

I got it working based on saaj's answer, but i want to move the code to index(), and the urls all return 404.

```
import cherrypy

class App:

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, id, name = None, **kwargs):
  if kwargs:
    # do your querystring processing
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(cherrypy.url())

  if not name:
    # get name part for canonical url
    name = '{0}/hello-world'.format(id)
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(cherrypy.url(name))

    return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(id, name, kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/post', config)
```

anymore help is much appreciated. i am still a beginner of cheerypy.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='/post/12345/hello-world'>/post/12345/hello-world</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='/post/12345/hello-world?from=something&else=123'>
            /post/12345/hello-world?from=something&else=123</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='/post/12345'>/post/12345 (more like SO)</a></li>        
      </ul>
    '''

  @cherrypy.expose
  def post(self, id, name = None, **kwargs):       
    if kwargs:
      # do your querystring processing
      raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(cherrypy.url())

    if not name:
      # get name part for canonical url
      name = '{0}/hello-world'.format(id)
      raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect(cherrypy.url(name))

    return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(id, name, kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: when i move the content of the post() to index(), then cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/post', config). it returns 404 again. any idea?

Comment: @triston You see this behaviour because [``index`` method](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/tutorial/dispatching.html#index-methods) is special one. Here's the quote ``However, unlike all other page handlers, it cannot take positional arguments``. Also note CherryPy's notion of application. It's one that you mount to the tree either with ``cherrypy.quickstart`` or ``cherrypy.tree.mount``. It usually covers a bigger self-contained scope, like blog, shop or admin panel. So for your first steps with CherryPy you may want to stay with single app approach for simplicity.